# How can I write a regular expression in python that stops at the first period in a string, which has unpredictable kinds of characters?

Tags: python, regex

I have several million equations such as this: `an equation: a(%)^ + b# = (+)C!.`

What I want returned is: `a(%)^ + b# = (+)C!`

Things that will always be true for the equation:
1. It will begin with "an equation  :"
2. It will contain an equal sign (=) between two spaces.
3. It will contain any number of plus signs (+) between two space.
4. It will end with a period (.).

Things that can be true:
1. The equation can contain additional + and =, though not delineated by spaces.
2. The equation can contain additional information following the period, and that information may contain a period. For example:

```
an equation: a(%)^ + b# = (+)C!. An annotation about the (!!*) equation.
```

3. I suppose it's possible that there are periods within the equation. I doubt it, and I think that if they do occur, they will come before (left side) of the equal sign.
4. The equation may not exist. The string will never be empty, but it may not contain an equation (i.e., with the four always true criteria).

Here is what I have so far:

```
e = "an equation: a(%)^ + b# = (+)C!. An annotation about the (!!*) equation."
rx = re.search(r'(?<=an equation:\s)(.*=.*)\.?',e)
print rx.group(0)
```

Let me explain each part of the regex:
`(r'(?<=an equation:\s)` finds "an equation" plus any amount of white space but does not retain it.
`(.*=.*)` asserts that there must be an equal sign. I have found that this is almost certainly going to universally exclude non-equations. If it doesn't, I can detect and deal with a few miscellaneous cases.
`.\?` In my mind, this should find the first period (i.e., escaped from the typical interpretation of . using ) after the = sign and then stop. However, that's not the case.

My regex returns:

```
a(%)^ + b# = (+)C!. An annotation about the (!!*) equation.
```

I think that that `.\?` and the greedy nature of the regex is the problem. I have tried many other combinations with `.\` and `?` and `[]` with and without `()`. These all return either as above with the second statement about annotation or a `NoneType` (i.e., no match). I feel now at a complete loss of how to stop after the first period.

Thank you in advance for your help. I have spent two days now on this site and using the Python docs to try and resolve this problem. I am just not not able to find/understand what I need.

Comment: Won't `(.*)\.` work?

Comment: Are each of these one line? What form do these equations come in together. Could you not just substring each line for 12 characters in until the second last character?

Comment: @SuperStew I believe that will stop at the last period, you would need to make it non-greedy.

Comment: @SuperStew - I tried what you suggested as `rx = re.search(r'(?<=an equation:\s)(.*=.*)(.*)\.',e)` And this returned  `a(%)^ + b# = (+)C!. An annotation about the (!!*) equation.` To be clear, that's with the `.` at the end of the annotation statement, too.

Comment: To stop at the next period seen, try using `[^\.]+\.`

Comment: @Sam - There are a few problems with the substring, if you mean that I could use it to replace `(?<=an equation:\s)`. Though the equation will be the first thing on a line if it exists, there could be white space at the beginning of the line, though rare probably, the other statements, like my annotation example, are also on the same line as the equation.

Comment: Do all of them have `an equation`?

Comment: Have you tried going line by line, clearing the white space at the start of the line and then checking to see if the line then starts with 'an equation:' ?

Comment: `r'an equation:\s(.+?)\.'` may be sufficient. The positive lookbehind assertion isn't necessary, since you aren't try to capture that portion of the match.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `.split('.')` ? Can this resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The greedy nature of regex is indeed the problem. Try this instead:

`rx = re.search(r'(?<=an equation:\s)(.*=[^\.]*)\.',e)`

The 2 differences are that I removed the '?' after your final period, as it is not optional according to Things That Will Always Be True #4. Then I told the greedy bit after the equals sign that it can match anything *except* a period. This means that it will stop matching once it reaches that first, non-optional period.

As a quick tip, I used [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/QUKh35/1) to quickly debug your regex. I highly recommend it for building regular expressions!

Comment: nice, regex puzzles are always fun, in a weird "i love to torture myself" kind of way

Comment: Thank you. This is a great tool. I saw lots of screen shots of it here as I was hunting for answers, but I did not explore it as I should have. I also see that I can `(?=\.)` to omit the period following the equation.